# Default "top sites/home page" in Safari

Tags: safari

I'm a new Mac user. When I 1st opened Safari, I changed the home page and therefore the top sites. I want to go back to the default home page/top sites that was set at the factory.  It showed a lot of news sources, CNN, etc that my husband wants to see, and I can't figure how to get back to it. Does anyone know the default?

Answer (score 2):

The home page is: http://livepage.apple.com/

But if you want to reset the top sites, Click on the Safari menu, Reset Safari and uncheck all but "Reset Top Sites" and click the Reset button.

Comment: The reset didn't go back for me.  I think I need to add the "news" choice back to the bookmark bar

Answer (score 2):

Preferences -> General -> There you can choose the default home page and choose with what page does a new tab or a new window opens i.e. : Top Sites.

Answer (score 0):

Top Sites is designed to change as you use the internet — it shows your most-visited websites, and it will constantly change.

You can find the stock Apple sites in your bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your history using `Safari -> Reset Safari (Check clear history)` and then Quit Safari (apple key + Q) simply closing the windows does not quit  Safari.

Launch Finder and goto: `your-home-folder > Library > Safari`
and delete `TopSites.plist`

This will reset the Top Sites with the defaults. Restart Safari.

Comment: It said the folder can't be found

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you guys and I have finally figured out how to solve it. Go to "Preferences" by clicking "Safari" at the top left corner.
When you open it, you will see "New windows open with:". Next to that, you have to click and select "Favorites" on that row and close the tab. And that's it, all done and set.

You're welcome.